# Tomcat listening on port 80, but does not respond

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Tomcat server running on Digital Ocean, and up until a few hours ago everything was going fine with no problems.

After re-deploying a WAR, I cant connect whatsoever.

It just times-out in the browser, with nothing happening.

Tomcat should be listening on port :80. Dump from netstat -tulpn:

```
tcp6 0 0 :::80  LISTEN 21571/java
tcp6 0 0 :::443 LISTEN 21571/java
```

Everything is working when I'm PING'ing the domain also. And i can start/stop the server with no problems.

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Updated with server.xml

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="443" />
```

Comment: Better suited for serverfault I think

Comment: check ${TOMCAT_HOME}/logs/catalina.out

Comment: It just reports that my Spring Application has been start as usual. And the catalina log says nothing either.

Comment: Please show your server.xml, please note that by default the port is 8080 on tomcat

Comment: Added server.xml connector configuration. Yes I know, but up until a few hours ago there was no problem. I have no idea what caused it.